# How to disable action button for n seconds after renderPlot update

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

I am very new to programming in R/Shiny: I'll try my best to state my question precisely.

The app below is a simple app of choice between two alternatives. In the app, option A updates every time that one clicks on one of the action buttons, while option B stays fixed.

What I am trying to do is to disable both action buttons after each time that the plot is updated, to "force" the user to stare at the two updated alternatives for at least a minimum number of seconds (in the code below, 3).

Since the plot updates every time one clicks on an action button, I have tried using `Sys.sleep(3)` between the disable and enable functions  (in the shinyjs package) inside `observeEvent(input$action2_pe,...)` and `observeEvent(input$action1_pe,...)` but this only invalidates both buttons while the plot is still updating, so that as a result the buttons get disabled and then enabled again only before the plot gets updated.

Another equivalent attempt (code below) has been using `Sys.sleep(3)` between the disable and enable functions inside `observe({output$plotA=renderPlot({...})` and `observe({output$plotB=renderPlot({...})` but the same result as above obtains (i.e. it disables and enables the button before showing the updated plot).

Any idea/suggestion on how to get to disable and then enable again the buttons only after the plot gets updated each time?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(id="main",title="Example disable-enable actionbutton after plotoutput update",

                shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                  fluidRow(wellPanel(
                                splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
                                column(12,align="center",
                                plotOutput("plotA",width="100%"),
                                actionButton("buttonA", label = "Choice A")),
                                column(12,align="center",
                                plotOutput("plotB",width="100%"),
                                actionButton("buttonB", label = "Choice B")
                                                    )))))



server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv=reactiveValues()
  range=10

######

  s_data=data.frame(X2=c(500,400,300,200,100), Y2=c(0,0,0,0,0))
  q=1
  m=dim(s_data)[1]
  s_data=s_data[sample(1:m,m),]

  rv$X2=s_data[q,"X2"]; 
  rv$Y2=s_data[q,"Y2"]; 

  observe({rv$pres=0.5*(rv$X2 + rv$Y2)})
  observe({rv$dmin=rv$Y2 ; rv$dmax=rv$X2}) 

  rv$q=1

####  

  fun=function(a1,b1,c1){

    totlength=100

    plot(NA,xlim=c(-10,totlength),ylim=c(0,10),
         axes=F,xlab="",ylab="")

    if (b1>a1){
    text(45,0,paste("Adopt", round(c1,digits=0), "cats" ,"in", 2 , "days"))
    }

    if (a1>b1){
    text(45,0,paste("Adopt", rv$X2, "cats" ,"in", 10 , "years"))
    }
  }

####

step_pe=reactive((rv$dmax-rv$dmin)<=range)

observe({output$plotA=renderPlot({
          par(fig = c(0,1,0,1))
          fun(1,2,rv$pres)

          shinyjs::disable("buttonA")
          shinyjs::disable("buttonB")
          Sys.sleep(3)
          shinyjs::enable("buttonA")
          shinyjs::enable("buttonB")

    })})


observe({output$plotB=renderPlot({
          par(fig = c(0,1,0,1))
          fun(2,1,rv$pres)

          shinyjs::disable("buttonA")
          shinyjs::disable("buttonB")
          Sys.sleep(3)
          shinyjs::enable("buttonA")
          shinyjs::enable("buttonB")

    })})



observeEvent(input$buttonA,{

      if(!step_pe()){
      rv$dmax=rv$pres
      temp1=round(0.5*(rv$dmin+rv$pres)/range)
      rv$pres=range*temp1

      }
    })

observeEvent(input$buttonB,{
    if (!step_pe()){
      rv$dmin=rv$pres
      temp1=round(0.5*(rv$dmax+rv$pres)/range)
      rv$pres=range*temp1

    }  
    })



}  


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Have a look at the `debouce` I think this is what you need https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.4/debounce.html

Comment: The suggestion above would probably work for you (debounce). You can also maybe try shinyjs::delay instead of Sys.sleep

Comment: I have used 'shinyjs::delay' and it worked like a charm! Thank you so much!! I will also try 'debounce' asap and let you know. I am immensely grateful for your time and help :)